# Creating Union of Sets using Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Ok, so I have been thinking about this for days and I am really unsure how to approach these problems. So I need to do the following:

- create a union method (i.e. union(set)) that creates a union for two sets. This method should somehow invoke the element method, a method whose specifications are mentioned below
- create an operator overloaded method (+) that represents the union of sets (not sure why they are different, but that's what the specifications ask for). This method must also invoke the union method
- element (int) that checks if the elements are a part of the set, I have a method below, but I am not sure if it's right
- operator overload method that adds an element to a new set

If you could address at least one of these, i would greatly appreciate it, I am really struggling to understand how to address these specifications. Thanks so much for your help!

```
#ifndef SET_H
#define SET_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Set{

        friend ostream &operator<< ( ostream &, const Set &);
        friend istream &operator>> ( istream &, Set &);

        public:

                Set ( int = DEFAULTSIZE ); //default constructor
                Set ( const Set & ); //copy constructor
                Set ( int [], int, char ); //constructor passing array of integers, size, name of set

                ~Set(); //destructor

                //assignment operator
                const Set &operator= ( const Set &);
                //equality operator
                bool operator== ( const Set & ) const;
                //inequality operator
                bool operator!= ( const Set &s1) const{
                        return !(*this == s1);
                }
                //subscript operators
                int &operator[] ( int );
                int operator[] ( int ) const;

                //methods to find union, intersection, and difference of sets
                Set Union ( Set & );
                Set Intersect ( Set & );
                Set Difference ( Set & );

                Set operator+ ( Set & ); //to represent union of two sets
                Set operator^ ( Set & ); //to represent intersection of two sets
                Set operator- ( Set & ); //to represent difference between two sets

                bool element ( int );

        private:
                static const int DELIM = -999; // delimiter to signal end of input
                static const int DEFAULTSIZE = 10;
                int numOfElements;
                int psize; //physical size of array
                int *set; //pointer array to represent set

};
#endif

//SOURCE FILE

//default constructor
Set::Set ( int s ){

        if ( s > 0 )
                psize = s;
        else
                psize = DEFAULTSIZE;
        //allocate an array of specified size
        set = new int[ psize ];

        if(!set) {
                //send an error is system cannot allocate memory
                cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory, exiting program... " << endl;
                exit (1);
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                set[i] = 0;
                numOfElements = 0;
        }

}

//copy constructor
Set::Set ( const Set &setToCopy): psize(setToCopy.psize){
        set = new int[psize];
        if(!set){
                cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory, exiting program..." << endl;
                exit (1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < psize; i++ ){
                set[i] = setToCopy.set[i];

                numOfElements = psize;
        }
}

Set::~Set(){
        if (set)
                delete [] set;
        set = NULL;
}

const Set &Set::operator= ( const Set &s1 ){
        if ( &s1 != this){
                if (numOfElements != s1.numOfElements){
                        delete [] set;
                        psize = numOfElements;
                        set = new int [psize];
                        if (!set){
                                cout << "Cannot Allocate memory, exiting program..." << endl;
                                exit (1);
                        }
                }
        }
        //assign contents of the array on the right to the contents of the array on the left
        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++ ){
                set[i] = s1.set[i];
                numOfElements = psize;
        }

        return (*this);
}

bool Set::operator== ( const Set &s1 ) const {
        bool validate = true;

        if ( numOfElements == s1.numOfElements ){
                for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++){
                        if ( set [i] != s1.set[i] ){
                                validate = false;
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        return (validate);
}

int &Set::operator[]( int subscript ){
        if ( subscript < 0 || subscript >= psize ) {
                cout << " Error, exiting program... " ;
                exit (1);
        }

        return set[subscript];
}
bool Set::element ( int n ) {
        bool validate = false;
        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
            if ( set[i] = n ) 
                validate = true;
        }                                                                       
        return (validate);
}
```

Comment: I assume that this is for a school (or similar) assignment, because there are already a [set in the standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), as well as [some set operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Set_operations_.28on_sorted_ranges.29).

Comment: Yes, it is for a school assignment. I am aware that there is set in the standard library, but I really do not think we are supposed to use that

Comment: Pick one task, try it, write what doesn't work. This is where I can help. I really doubt anyone will write the code for you if you just say what you need to do.

Comment: My problem is that I am unsure how to write a method that takes the union of two sets. I understand that I am supposed to copy the elements of one array into another array and check to make sure that none of the elements of the first set are elements in another set, but i am really unsure how to even begin writing a method like this

Comment: I think your `element(int n)`  function is not correct. The `n` is a value that may occur somwhere in your array `int * set`. So you will need to loop over your array and check if any value in the array is equal to `n`. If you find one return `true`, otherwise return `false`.

Comment: So I edited my element ( int n ) function, but I am unsure how to incorporate this into a union of sets, do you have any suggestions??